# How to add swipe event to a container in sencha touch

Tags: extjs

I have a view of xtype container. If I swipe from left to right the view must change. It is more or less similar to carousel but I dont need carousel. I need to navigate between views with the help of swipe event.

Answer (score 1):

```
listeners: {
    painted:function(container) {
        container.getContentEl().on('swipe',function() {
           // your swipe code here
        }
    }
}
```